# Disaster Recovery for S3 Bucket with a lot Parquet Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, disaster-recovery

I have an S3 bucket with a lot of parquet split files within each partition. All files in the bucket are highly important to business and in case anyone deletes them that will be a disaster. Now, if i use Glacier/Glacier D.Arch., I'm concerned that my retrieval costs in case of failure will be too high because of number of individual parquet files. How can I best create Disaster Recovery for such a bucket with least cost? (Assuming users are not deleting necessary data every month ofc.)

**Example Case:**
Consider this, I have 100 GB of data, full of 150 KB files. Annual additional cost of 1 accidental delete in Glacier is 53 USD, while on Glacier Deep Arch its 82.4 USD. Now simply change the per file size from 150 KB to 1024 KB. These costs change to 21 USD for Glacier and 16 USD for Glacier Deep Arch. My main problem number of parquet files here that raise the cost of affordable retrieval.

Comment: Well, there is a trade-off between storage cost and retrieval cost (w.r.t. both time and $). Could you provide further details about how often these files are retrieved, what the file sizes are, and at what scale?

Comment: I should've made this clear, current versions are in Standard S3. I want DR on them in case someone deletes everything in bucket. Files are Parquet files, On average around 150 KB each (6990 files per GB). Recovery will only be in case when someone deletes everything in the bucket, let's say this happens once a year. Let's say we are talking about 100 GB of total bucket size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to prevent someone from deleting objects accidentally, I don't think S3 Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive is the right way to go. Instead, you can achieve this by enabling [object versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html) and [MFA delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMFADelete.html).

Also keep in mind, Amazon S3 Glacier and S3 Glacier Deep Archive have an overhead of additional 32KB per object. <strike>Considering your objects are 150 KB on average, this would lead to a 21.3% cost increase.</strike>

Comment: You got the closest to my problem. :)
Enabling object versioning, yes, that's what I want to do. Then I want to take prev. versions to low storage costs, the problem now, (as you mentioned) becomes the number of files to restore as parquet is pro in creating small files, for good reason.

Comment: @AwaisKaleem Will your objects be overwritten, or do they remain untouched in future? What would be a "previous version"?

Comment: Each file will be overwritten at least once in two months. In that case definition of previous version becomes the version before being overwritten. In this case, previous version is needless. In case of accidental delete however, previous version is the file that should not have been deleted.

Comment: @jellycsc, turns out a simple object versioning+mfa is the cheapest in this case. I wonder if AWS will ever do something about this "per 1000 requests" charges in glacier. Anyways, thanks a lot for understanding my question requirements first. Making this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I can't do the math quicky to compare costs, but if you are mostly worried about accidental file deletions, and if normally the files are just put there and not replaced on a regular basis, you could consider turning on S3 versioning - that way you can recover old versions of files if someone overwrites one of them, and if a users deletes them, they don't actually get deleted.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-enhancement-versioning/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this case, I'll pay additional cost for previous versions. Now lets assume I have a life cycle rule that puts them to Glacier/Deep Archieve, my costs are still high because of number of files i have per GB (699 files/GB).

Answer (score 0):

Glacier/Glacier Deep Archive will always be the most cost effective so I would not worry about the cost of retrieval.

Outside of that you can use [replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) to another S3 bucket to run a duplicate of the files, you could combine this with a [lifecycle rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to lower the price class to infrequent access.

Additionally based on your concern of accidental deletes is it not possible to prevent your team members from having the [DeleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html) permission for this specific bucket?

Comment: Thank you. But consider this, I have 100 GB of data, full of 150 KB files. Annual additional cost of 1 accidental delete in Glacier is 53 USD, while on Glacier Deep Arch its 82.4 USD. Now simply change the per file size from 150 KB to 1024 KB. These costs change to 21 USD for Glacier and 16 USD for Glacier Deep Arch. My main problem number of parquet files here that raise the cost of affordable retrieval.

As for deleteObject, its a complex mess, long story short, its basically overwrites not deletes. :(

Comment: If it overwrites definitely consider object versioning, and migrate previous versions to infrequent access.